# How to add an already existing PropertyGroup to a CollectionProperty

Tags: python

I want to be able to create pointers to property groups that already exist. Imagine I have a collection of scene MaterialGroups which are defined like this:

```
class MaterialGroup(PropertyGroup):
    weighted_materials: bpy.props.CollectionProperty(
        type=WeightedMaterialListItem
    )
    list_index: bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name="Index for the list of weighted materials",
        default=0,
        min=0
    )
    material_to_add: bpy.props.PointerProperty(
        type=bpy.types.Material,
        update=material_to_add_changed
    )
    name: bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="Name",
        description="The name of the material group",
        update=avoid_duplicate_names
    )
```

The scene has a big collection of these, and I've set up the scene collection like this:

```
class MaterialGroups(PropertyGroup):
    groups: bpy.props.CollectionProperty(
        type=MaterialGroup
    )
    list_index: bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name="Index for list of material groups",
        default=0,
        min=0
    )
...
def register():
    ...
    bpy.types.Scene.material_groups = bpy.props.PointerProperty(
        type=MaterialGroups
    )
```

Imagine that I want an individual object to be able to have its own set of material groups. The user can only add material groups to the object that have already been added to the scene, and the object's material groups should update if the scene material groups are updated (ideally I would like a material group in the object to point to a material group from the scene).

```
class ObjectSettings(PropertyGroup):

    material_groups: bpy.props.CollectionProperty(
        type=MaterialGroup
    )
...
def register():
    ...
    bpy.types.Object.settings = bpy.props.PointerProperty(
        type=ObjectSettings)
```

I can add a new, default MaterialGroup to an object by doing something like:

```
bpy.context.active_object.settings.material_groups.add()
```

But how can I make it so that the material group that is added is a pointer to one of the scene material groups?

If I give the MaterialGroup created by `.add()` the values from a scene material group that I want it to point to, then when something like the name is changed for a scene material group, then the object's version of this material group will not be updated because it acts as a deep copy of it instead of a pointer to it.

Any thoughts on how I can solve this issue? I realize that this is a kind of involved question, so if I can make anything more clear, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you make the `MaterialGroups` as `CollectionProperty` and add `object` as property?

Comment: @Karan Do you mean for each `MaterialGroup` in the `MaterialGroups`, having a `CollectionProperty` of `PointerProperty`s that point to each object it is assigned to?

Comment: You want to link the scene's `MaterialGroup` to the object's `MaterialGroup`, Right?

Comment: @Karan Well, I want an object to have a list of material groups that is a subset of the scene's material groups.

Comment: Come to discord, Karan#5503